# Equation and Align in Beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, align

Here is my code for `beamer`:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} %For making Greek letters bold
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        Align:
        \begin{align}
            1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^*\right] &\leq 1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}\right].\\
            \rightarrow \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^* &\leq \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}.
        \end{align}
        Equation:    
        \begin{equation}a
            1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^*\right] \leq 1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}\right].
        \end{equation}
        \begin{equation}
            \rightarrow \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^* \leq \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}.
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

For some reason, when I use `align`, the equation number (1) is listed below the respective equation instead of right next to it, compared to the equation number (3). Is there a way to fix the `align` environment such that the equation numbers are right next to their respective equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem isn't the use of the `align` environment. Instead, it's the abundant use of `\left` and `\right` to auto-size parentheses and brackets. `\left` and `\right` not only fail to resize any of their arguments (which isn't surprising, actually, as the material they enclose is neither tall nor deep), they also insert whitespace before each opening parenthesis and after each closing parenthesis.

The easiest -- and best, IMNSHO -- solution lies in getting rid of all `\left` and `\right` instructions. See equations (3) and (4) below.

If, for some reason, you can't quite drop the `\left`/`\right` safety blanket (possibly because you learned LaTeX from an OCD professor who had been raised to falsely believe that it's necessary to encase parenthetic expression in `\left`/`\right` pairs?), do yourself a favor and (a) load the `mleftright` package and (b) replace all instances of `\left` and `\right` with `\mleft` and `\mright`. That'll get rid of the excesssive-spacing issue as well. Oh, if you like the effect produced by `\mleft` and `\mright`, you can issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble and henceforth `\left` and `\right` will behave as `\mleft` and `\mright` do.

On a separate topic: Assuming all those superscript-T symbols denote transposition, I would employ a separate symbol for that action. In the code below, I propose a macro called `\transp` for the job. Of course, you're free to use another symbol than `\top`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\newcommand\transp{{}^{\raisebox{2pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\top}$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    Align with 8 instances of \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right}:
    \begin{align}
    1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^*\right] 
    &\leq 1 + \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\left[\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}^*,t\right) + \mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}\right].\\
     \rightarrow \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}^* 
     &\leq \bm{\lambda}^{*\text{T}}\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}^*, t\right)\mathbf{u}.
    \end{align}
    Align without \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right}:
    \begin{align}
    1 + \bm{\lambda}^*\transp  [\mathbf{f} (\mathbf{x}^*,t ) + \mathbf{g} (\mathbf{x}^*, t )\mathbf{u}^* ] 
    &\leq 1 + \bm{\lambda}^*\transp  [\mathbf{f} (\mathbf{x}^*,t ) + \mathbf{g} (\mathbf{x}^*, t )\mathbf{u} ].\\
    \rightarrow \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mathbf{g} (\mathbf{x}^*, t )\mathbf{u}^* 
    &\leq \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mathbf{g} (\mathbf{x}^*, t )\mathbf{u}.
    \end{align}
    Align with \texttt{\string\mleft} and \texttt{\string\mright}:
    \begin{align}
    1 + \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mleft[\mathbf{f}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*,t\mright) + \mathbf{g}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*, t\mright)\mathbf{u}^*\mright] 
    &\leq 1 + \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mleft[\mathbf{f}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*,t\mright) + \mathbf{g}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*, t\mright)\mathbf{u}\mright].\\
     \rightarrow \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mathbf{g}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*, t\mright)\mathbf{u}^* 
     &\leq \bm{\lambda}^*\transp \mathbf{g}\mleft(\mathbf{x}^*, t\mright)\mathbf{u}.
    \end{align}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I personally like to use the `\left` and `\right` delimiters because it helps me keep track of each side, and it can automatically adjust its size if the expressions inside them are big.

Comment: That's why I provided the suggestion to employ the `mleftright` package: It lets you keep the all-important safety blanket but doesn't insert excessive amounts of whitespace...

Comment: @Mico For general purposes, do you recommend using the `mleftright` package or manually resizing delimiters, e.g., using `\big`, or something else entirely?

Comment: @bclzyjhr - You ask two separate questions; the first concerns horizontal spacing, and the second pertains to vertical sizing. First, on employing the `mleftright` package: I'm not aware of any downsides to using this package (and enabling it globally by running `\mleftright`). Second, on the best way, or ways, to size delimiters: I think it's a really good idea to be fully proficient in both types of methods, i.e., both the automatic method via `\left` and `\right` and the manual method.

Comment: @Mico Oh, I see. Thank you for the explanation!